# Different behavior of `man` for root and user

Tags: linux, shell

Recently a user asked me for help and wrote:

> "Why does invoking `man /bin/find` display gibberish?"

I answered that he was using `man` incorrectly by providing a path, that `man` was interpreting the executable as a man page source file, and that he should only provide the name of the subject without a path, i.e. `man find`. It was then that he sprang the question that stumped me:

> "Well then, why does it work if I do it as root, i.e. `sudo man /bin/find`?"

I tried it, and sure enough, when invoked as root using `sudo` or from a root shell, `sudo man /bin/find` displays the man page instead of the executable.

- There's nothing special about `find`; this works for any executable.
- This occurs on RHEL 7 and 8, but on Mac OS it displays the binary as root or user.
- I can find no mention of this in the man page for `man`.
- I made a reality check: `ls -i man` and `sudo ls -i man` return the same inode.  Same for `/bin/find`.
- `man` has not been aliased.
- Running it in a `bash -x` shell does not reveal any substitutions.

Surely I've overlooked something simple; what is the explanation for this phenomenon?

Comment: `man /bin/find` works for me as a regular user (Ubuntu 20.04, bash and zsh, CentOS 7).

Comment: Thanks for adding another data point.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I've tested it and you are right. The thing you overseen is that `man /usr/bin/find` display page, not binary. More than that if you add `/bin` to `$PATH` it will display page instead of binary for `man /bin/find` as well. You also can check that real root (not sudo) will display binary.

So what is happening here:

1. `Man` strip path from the argument if this path present in `$PATH`. It seems to be quite obvious for `man` to strip any executable path not to display binary files. Maybe they have no other way to distinguish binary file from term in argument.
2. To prevent unauthorized command being run sudo have its own `PATH` defined in `secure_path` in `/etc/sudoers` which is `/sbin:/bin:/usr/sbin:/usr/bin` on EL systems and any command run by `sudo` have another `PATH` environment.
3. In EL systems `/bin/find` is a hardlink for `/usr/bin/find` and `/bin` is not added to `$PATH` by default. This cause `man` not to understand this is binary, but `sudo` add `/bin` to `$PATH` so `man` now become capable of understanding.

Comment: I don't think that `sudo` changes `/bin/find` to `/usr/bin/find`. It's an argument to the command and sudo shouldn't change arguments. I guess the real reason is that sudo resets `$PATH` and adds `/bin` to it. And now `man` sees that `/bin/find` is a command in `$PATH` and not just a random file.

Comment: It certainly does. Make restriction to /bin/systemctl and hardlink for it and then call sudo ./systemctl. However you are right that `sudo` changes `PATH` variable, and questioned mechanism works your way, not mine. Thanks. My initial thought have no sense since /bin/find is not an executed element here, only man is.

Comment: I believe it changes `man` to `/usr/bin/man`. But I really doubt it changes `man`'s arguments.

Comment: Surely, I just read your comment not thoroughly, sorry. Thanks again.

Comment: @kab00m Did you find documentation about man's path-stripping behavior, or deduce it?

Comment: Deduced, but proved with running `man -d`. man.c:3891 says: `/* Perhaps an executable. If its directory is on $PATH, then we want to look up the corresponding manual page in the appropriate hierarchy rather than displaying the executable.*/`